# Объясните наглядно разницу раннего и позднего связывания методов.

Tags: java

Позднее связывание методов это когда имеется ссылочная переменная, и в зависимости от того экземпляр какого класса будет создан, и будет вызван соответствующий метод. А как насчет раннего связывания в чем отличие?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Раннее связывание - это когда метод, который будет вызван, известен во время компиляции, например, вызов статического метода.

Кстати, то что вы называете поздним связываением, есть скорее dynamic dispatch.

Позднее связывание - это когда вызов метода может быть осуществлен только во время выполнения и у компилятора нет информации, чтобы проверить корректность такого вызова. В java это можно сделать при помощи рефлексии.

Comment: Можно пример позднего связывания

Comment: Вот пример:

    Object a = ...   // какое-то присваивание
    a.toString();

На этапе компиляции мы не знаем, какого типа объект `a`. Он может быть как собственно `Object`, так и любым его наследником, в котором метод `toString()` переопределён. Именно на этапе выполнения определяется тип `a` и вызывается `toString()` из того класса, какого типа объект `a`. Это и есть позднее связывание.

Comment: @JAVAVladuxa, посмотри http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_Java

Answer (score 9):

Раннее связывание, как было отмечено выше, происходит на этапе компиляции. Оно применяется при вызове обычных методов (не виртуальных).

Позднее связывание напротив происходит во время выполнения. Выполняется оно при вызове виртуальных функций класса-потомка для определения того, какой именно метод следует вызывать.

Исходя из того, что раннее связывание выполняется на этапе компиляции, а позднее - в рантайме, первый вариант обладает лучшим быстродействием, однако второй необходим для реализации полиморфизма.

По поводу Java могу сказать, что там, если не ошибаюсь, ко всем методам по умолчанию применяется позднее связывание (если они не помечены модификатором final) в отличие от, скажем, С++, где по умолчанию применяется раннее связывание.
Еще для большего понимания вопроса почитайте про [таблицу виртуальных методов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2)

З.Ы. с Java близко не знаком, поэтому точно не могу сказать, насколько там применим термин "функция"

Comment: > Раннее связывание, как было отмечено выше, происходит на этапе компиляции. Оно применяется при вызове обычных методов (не виртуальных).

если компилятор явно видит, какой метод будет вызван, даже если метод находится "под сильнейшим полиморфизмом", то компилятору никто не мешает сделать раннее связывание.

Но в java это ещё больше размазывается. jit может понять, какой метод вызывается и сгенерировать код эквивалентный раннему связыванию.

Comment: @DreamChild не ко всем методам по умолчанию применяется позднее связывание, в русском переводе "Философия Java" неверно перевели, теперь многие повторяют ту же ошибку. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1351859/%d0%92-java-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5