# В Java связывание всех методов осуществляется через позднее связывание?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот сейчас читаю *Брюс Эккель - Философия Java*, написано (241 стр.) что в Java

> связывание **всех методов** в Java осуществляется поли­морфно, через позднее связывание

и в то же время чуть ранее было написано что

> Для всех методов Java используется механизм позднего связывания, если
> только метод не был объявлен как final

ну и в интернете поискал информацию: вызов статических методов и методов через super использует раннее связывание.

Первое утверждение получается ложно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, трудности перевода. В оригинале написано (4-е издание, стр.196 ):

> All method binding in Java uses late binding unless the method is **static** or **final** (private methods are implicitly final). This means that ordinarily you don’t need to make any decisions about whether late binding will occur - it happens automatically.

И далее:

> Once you know that all method binding in Java **happens polymorphically via late binding**, you can write your code to talk to the base class and know that all the derived-class cases will  work correctly using the same code.

Т.е. **полиморфизм** работает через механизм позднего связывания.

Comment: ну как раз выражение "Как только вы узнаете, что все связывание методов в Java происходит полиморфно с помощью позднего связывания" противоречит тому, что в Java существует раннее связывание для методов, смысл противоречия тот же.

Comment: @Merlin Возможно фраза на английском неудачная. По-русски я бы сказал: "Связывание всех полиморфных методов происходит с помощью позднего связывания." В Java все методы по умолчанию полиморфны, т.е. тут не нужно писать `virtual` как в С++, чтобы сделать метод полиморфным. Но с другой стороны, если метод помечен как `private`, `static`, `final` или если это конструктор, то для такого метода полиморфизм невозможен и тут вступает в дело раннее связывание.

Comment: Ну да, так смысл другой получается, касается только методов используемых в полиморфизме.

Answer (score -2):

Это логично static final и private методы не могут бы переопределены, поэтому их связывание происходит во время компиляция(раннее связывание), как я понимаю например метод this.execute() вот не поймешь this чего во время компиляции? поэтому позднее связывание только для методов которые можно переопределить и связывание происходит